# Asp.net web application and sharepoint list

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, custom-lists

net application on visual studio and i need to make connection with sharepoint costum list to update/insert/delete.
Is there any tutorial or anyone can give some help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple things you need to consider.

**Code to write**

- Download and reference SharePoint Client dll's (e.g. SP 2013 -> 15
  [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585))
- Check out these samples -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee539976(v=office.14).aspx

**Authentication**

- 'Normal' service account authentication
- AddIn Authentication (https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/sp-add-ins/package-and-publish-high-trust-sharepoint-add-ins)

For a test drive i recommend the first authentication option, as the AddIn option requires a lot of configurations steps...

1. Make sure the service account of your Web Application (IIS Pool Account Identity or any other credentials) has sufficient permissions in SharePoint
2. Create the ClientContext as seen in the samples above